# Prove function is strictly decreasing over interval

Tags: calculus

Prove $f(x) = \frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^2}{2} + x + 1$ is strictly decreasing over $x \in [-3, -2].$

I remember looking at these type of questions during my undergrad but completely forgot how to do it.

Comment: Hint: derivatives.

Comment: @SeanRoberson How do I prove $f'(x) < 0$ over $(-3, 0)$?

Comment: if we take the first $n$ terms in the Taylor expansion of $e^x,$   when $n$ is even, the polynomial is positive. When $n$ is odd, a single root. On this site many times.

Comment: @WillJagy Which "statement lacking proof" is false?

Comment: @coffeemath the question originally gave the interval as $-3 <x<0$

Comment: The derivative is a geometric series. Apply a sign analysis on the numerator and denominator once you get to that stage.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1$

$f'(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1$

pose $h(x) =f'(x)=\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1
 $

Let's show $ h(x) <0$

$h'(x) =\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1$

we know that : $x\in [-3,-2]$

So
$-3\leq x\leq - 2$$\Rightarrow $

$ 2\leq \frac{x^2} {2}\leq  \frac{9}{2}$

So

$0\leq h'(x)= \frac{x^2} {2}+x+1\leq  \frac{9}{2}-1$

$h(x)$ incremental

$h(-3)=-3$ and $h(-2)=-\frac{4}{3}$

So $\forall x\in [-3,-2]  h(x) <0$

We know $h(x) =f'(x) $

So finally:

$\forall x\in [-3,-2]  f'(x) <0$

$f$ is decreasing in $[-3,-2]$